# Is it possible to set a title attribute for a whole column within an html table?

Tags: html, html-table

Consider a really big html table.

If I want to have the same tooltip for every column in all rows I could set the title attribute for every single `<td>` tag. I wonder if there is a better way to this with html since this is a load of redundant data and increases the document size. Needs to work only in newest Chrome/Firefox.

If there is nothing like this I guess I could use Javascript to this, but I want to be sure first, that there is no other way.

Comment: I would try using a `<colgroup/>` tag, but with low expectations that it'll work. You could duplicate the `title` attribute using javascript rather than duplicating it in the document itself.

Comment: I would just use some scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered putting the title attribute onto the table itself? That way you effectively have a title attribute for all the TDs.

If you're wanting to try and avoid giving it to the THs, you can get away with altering the TH to have a title of " ", and that as far as I can tell gets rid of the unwanted title tag.

I've only tested this in Firefox though, I'm unsure if it'll work as you want in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have different titles for every column and not just one title for every column..